# Get last item with date range and name filter in google sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have the below set of records in Google Sheets. I would like to filter the rows with specific name and date range. Once I have the filtered data, I would like to fetch the last row's final amount cell data.

[image]

**Ex:** I would like to fetch **final amount** as **300** if my date(dd/mm/yyyy) range is **01/01/206 to 11/06/2016** and Name selection is '**Sandeep**'.

As I have experience SQLite db, I have inserted the same records in DB and got the expected result using the below query.

```
select Final from MyTable where Date in (select max(Date) from MyTable WHERE Date BETWEEN '01/01/2016' AND '11/06/2016' and name = "Sandeep")
```

But I am not getting idea how to use multiple select statements in google sheets. It is ok for me to get result using any other way. So please help me to get the result as explained above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
= QUERY (A1:E50,"Select F where A > date '2016-1-1' and A < date '2016-6-11' and B ='Sandeep' order by A desc limit 1")
```

- Use Column IDs `A,B,C` instead of `name, income`. Multiple columns can be given in a single `Select` clause separated by a `,`
- Dates in `where` clause should be written in `yyyy-mm-dd` format only(regardless of the format of dates in actual column)

Answer (score 2):

See if this works

```
=index(E:E, max(filter(row(A:A), A:A>date(2016, 1, 1), A:A<date(2016, 6, 11), B:B="Sandeep")))
```

If you want to include start and end date, change > to >= and < to <=.

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. But I would like to use the name condition too. Please update for that.