# Return the most current entry based on a column and row evaluation

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I'm sure that what I'm trying to do isn't too unusual, but this is not my bag so I'm reaching out in the hope that there's a brain out there that can guide me in the right direction.

I've created an online form (using a 3rd party app) for staff to update the whereabouts of particular tools/equipment. The results get exported into a basic spreadsheet (of which I have no control over the format). From this spreadsheet, I want to create my own sheet which takes data from the most current entry for each item.

So there needs to be an evaluation of the date, a search for a particular text string, and then the return of a text string in a corresponding cell. Does that make any sense?

Comment: Keep in mind that we cannot see what you see (sheets, layout, data types, input means, ranges, number of columns, headers, etc.) and we do not know what you know about what you're trying to do. So while your post likely makes perfect sense to you, that is only because you can see the data and you know the end goal. From out here, there is currently no way to help you. Consider sharing a link to a sample spreadsheet containing a subset of your actual sheet data, including correct sheet names, where you want to enter search criteria, what the results should be, etc.

Comment: perhaps you can find the answer here: [Get last item with date range and name filter in google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48722672/get-last-item-with-date-range-and-name-filter-in-google-sheets)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask